# Using a variable out of an anonymous function

Tags: php, return, anonymous-function

Given the following function, I need `calculateProducts()` to return the `$products` array.

```
public function calculateProducts($params)  {

     SoapWrapper::service('calculateProducts', 
        function ($service) use ($data) {
          $listProducts = $service->call('calculateProducts');
          foreach ($listProducts->return->productList as $pdt) {
              $product = new ProductsResult;
              $product->valueA = "a";
              $product->valueB  = "b";
              $product->save();
              $products[] = $product;
          }
        }
    );
    return $products;
}
```

This doesn't work : I guess I'm messing up with the anonymous function (which functions I struggle to read well for now) since `$products` is into it.

How to make `$products` "global" so that `calculateProducts()` can return it ?

I've tried to return `$products` into the anonymous function and then returning the value of the SoapWrapper object, of course this doesn't returns the array of ProductsResult objects needed, see below :

```
 public function calculateProducts($params)  {

         $pdts = SoapWrapper::service('calculateProducts', 
            function ($service) use ($data) {
              $listProducts = $service->call('calculateProducts');
              foreach ($listProducts->return->productList as $pdt) {
                  $product = new ProductsResult;
                  $product->valueA = "a";
                  $product->valueB  = "b";
                  $product->save();
                  $products[] = $product;
              }
            return $products;
           }
        );
        return $pdts;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

One should use a closure :

```
public function calculateProducts($params)  {
     function ($service) use ($data, &$products) {
          $listProducts = $service->call('calculateProducts');
          foreach ($listProducts->return->productList as $pdt) {
              $product = new ProductsResult;
              $product->valueA = "a";
              $product->valueB  = "b";
              $product->save();
              $products[] = $product;
          }
        }
    return $products;
}
```

The clue here is `function ($service) use ($data, &$products) {}`.